# Is using attack tools from a compromised host considered "pivoting"?

Tags: penetration-test, terminology

I would like to get a better understanding of pivoting in pentesting.
If I install attack tools (nmap, ...) on a compromised host and use them to attack other hosts on the network, is that considered pivoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify some relevant information:

- Is "the network" an internal network that the compromised machine has access to that your machine has no (or more restricted) access to?
- Do you mean "use" or "execute" rather than "install" and "recon tools" rather than "attack tools"?
- Do you use attack tools as well and not just recon tools?

If all those questions can be answered "yes", then yes.

As the word already implies, it means to use other resources to make things possible that were out of reach without a pivot point.

Think as that compromised machine as the pivot point you need for your crow bar to rest on when using the crow bar on a door. In this case, pivoting allows you to benefit from different restrictions that are often in place in local networks in contrast to the external interfaces.

If you only use a compromised host to re-route your attack traffic outside of that machines local network as means of hiding yourself, this would rather be proxy chaining than pivoting.

Comment: So if I have a shell on a box, and use that shell to execute tools like nmap in order to discover hosts on the local network, is that considered pivoting?

Comment: Those tools are usually not installed on those machines, but for example metasploit has the ability to re-route traffic through compromised hosts, utilizing their network interfaces which give you less restricted access to their local network. If you do something like that, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption in the term pivoting is correct - routing the attack traffic through an already compromised host for the purposes of accessing a resource you otherwise would not be able to access. I would, however, recommend not installing software on compromised hosts if it can be avoided. The more stealth you employ the better.

You could utilize an already compromised host with the usage of the `route` command in Metasploit if you have a meterpreter shell, or `proxychains`. These commands will allow your compromised host to act as a "forwarder" of traffic to whichever host you specify.

This is not to be confused with lateral movement, which is using attacks such as pass-the-hash or using cracked password hashes to log in to another resource than the one originally compromised.